# Исходный код на Java и C++ в репозитории Core в github

Tags: c#, .net

Кто-нибудь сможет объяснить назначение кода на Java в исходниках .NET, а также зачем C# сначала преобразуется в C++ при сборке программы?

Comment: примеры? Ну и мне кажется, что рантайм не обязательно должнен на 100% состоять из C#  кода

Comment: Ну теоретически c++ нужно когда требуется поддержка специфических архитектур. Или когда нужно написать managed обертку. Java скорее всего тоже используется для обертки.

Comment: Зря минусите. Человек узнать хочет почему так работает язык.

Comment: [Как задать хороший вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Все ядро .NET написано на C/C++. Виртуальная машина, компилятор и т.д.

Сначала код C# компилируется в CIL (Common Intermediate Language) и сохраняется в файл.

Затем, при запуске приложения загружается машина виртуальная машина .NET (которая и написана на C++), после этого она по мере вызовов методов превращает CIL в настоящий ассемблер код. Это называется JIT-компиляция (Just-in-time, прямо-во-время).

После ассемблер уже выполняется процессором.

Код, в который собирается C# не может работать на процессоре без виртуальной машины. Вот почему нужен более низкоуровневый язык.

Comment: Вот я и говорю, что между C# и CIL стоит C++. Почему - не знаю.

Comment: Я же объяснил почему :)

Comment: Код, который собирается в результате компилирования не может в чистом виде работать на процессоре. C++ нужен что бы превратить его в ASM и запустить на процессоре

Comment: Похожим методом работает язык Java.